# ShowDialog is just looping and creating new forms

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5

Some info:

- C#
- Winforms project in visual studio 2012
- .Net framework 4.5
- Windows 8.1 OS x64

I am having the strangest bug!
Whenever i use:

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TestForm form = new TestForm();
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```

*TestForm is just a stadard form with no controls added.*

It will stop the main thread as it should! But instead of waiting for input, it will spawn a new "form" ever 0.5 sec aprox... i took a new solution and tried, and there it worked fine, but in the app im currently working on, it does this when ever it is run somewhere inside or from this form.

Placing the same form code inside a BackGroundWorker, then it works fine.
ONLY inside the main UI form i have, where this error occurs..
Using `Show()` works as normal, only 1 form opens, but does not work with dialog result :-/

I have no idea why and have never seen this before??
please help.

EDIT:
I did as Roy Dictus suggested, and placed a break point.
This is in my LauncherFrom that load Main:

```
private void timerHide_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            // Open main form IF true else open hidden
            var f = new a.Views.Main();
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.StartHidden)
            {
                f.Opacity = 0;
                f.Show();
                f.Hide();
                f.Opacity = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                f.Show();
            }

            // Stop timer
            timerHide.Stop();
        }
```

And it looks like `timerHide.Stop();` is never being called.
I have used this many times before, and i have a few more `ShowDialog()` calls that work fine..

So why does this not work for only SOME of the `ShowDialog();`??
If i remove `TestForm.ShowDialog();` from `Main_Load()` it calls `timerHide.Stop();` just fine.

Comment: Your main form name is not TestForm? 
I mean you are not creating TestForm inside TestForm?

Comment: I'll bet that if you check, something is creating a new `Main` instance every 0.5 secs. What is `Main` (another form?) and where is the code that loads it? Are you using a Splash screen that loads Main?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `form.ShowDialog()` line, then look at the call stack to find out what causes your problem.

Comment: Hi, I have a LauncherForm that is the first thing that starts, and LauncherForm then load "Main".

Comment: Please supply SSCCE, or it never happened

Comment: Short, Self Contained, Correct Example. See http://sscce.org

Comment: @NielsSchmidt You could have typed SSCCE into google .....

Comment: @David Heffernan True, my head is not where it should be right now, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code never reaches `tiemrHide.Stop()`. That's because you show a modal dialog which runs its own message pump. And so your timer fires again and again.

Here's how it goes:

1. The timer event `timerHide_Tick` fires, and creates a new main form instance.
2. The new main form shows a modal dialog in `Main_Load`.
3. The modal dialog runs a message pump.
4. The timer event fires again.
5. Goto 1.

You need to call `Stop()` at the very start of `timerHide_Tick`.